# nftables script file is getting blank

Tags: firewall

I suppose that "nft list ruleset" only list current rules on my system.
Although, when I use...

> nft list ruleset > nftables.conf

...I expected to see the rules on this file, however my file get tottaly blank instead.

I suspect this command "nft list ruleset > nftables.conf" is wrong, even so why is this just erasing my nftables file?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this when I didn't run it as the root user. The nft tool quits with no errors when you're not root.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command `nft list ruleset` without root rights, it will print nothing. Redirecting nothing to the file with `> nftables.conf` will then end up erasing anything you had in that file.

I'd suggest first checking that the ruleset gets correctly displayed by running `sudo nft list ruleset` without the redirection to a file, and when the output looks good, add `> nftables.conf` to the command to save the output to file.